# Flutter Isar: Best Practice to generate data on installation/creation

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-sqlite, flutter-dependencies

I'm moving from SQLite to NoSQL using Isar for an app, and I noticed most NoSQL solutions don't have on database creation option.

And I need to create some default data on the app installation once, like settings, some default data like categories...etc

I can do it by setting a flag using SharedPrefrences and checking every time the user opens the app, but it seems not the best or kinda junky.

Does there anything else espcaily with Isar, I searched all the docs and could not find something!

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful: https://github.com/isar/isar/discussions/358